# Is there an OS without locking mechanisms (e.g. mutex)?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, mutex, semaphore, atomic

I've been re-reading my `Operating Systems 1` course script and found a curious note that reads: "*Someone wrote a whole OS without locking mechanisms!*", in the section about semaphore implementations. Now, it's been a few weeks since that and I don't want to flood the professor with e-mails about every little thing I find curious, but I still have to ask:

**Is there a (famous/modern) example of an OS written without locking mechanisms, that supports multiple threads?**

Keep in mind that he might've been refering to a student-made project, as we have to implement a fully functional kernel by the end of the course. I turned to SO because Google wasn't much of a help, turning up only some exotic implementations of semaphores/mutexes.

Comment: [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) is a good candidate (famous, not modern). :-)

Comment: CP/M, ISIS.....

Comment: 'exotic implementations of semaphores/mutexes' - not sure how those can be 'exotic', they support only two operations each, (lock, unlock, post, wait).

Comment: If you want to support multiple threads, You are going to have a really difficult time without those synchro mechanisms.